# SQL Server indexed views with a UNION

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that is very slow and I have to make that view indexed. The definition for my view is as follows:

```
create view abc
as
    select * from a

    union all 

    select * from b

    union all

    select * from c;
go
```

> I know that the basic requirement we have to create indexed view is not to have union or union all.

Any suggestions or way around to implement this?

Comment: Why do believe a view index will improve performance? If this view is used in queries that are slow, perhaps query and indexing tuning of the underlying tables will help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an index on a view that posses's a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Really no way around that unfortunately. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) outlines the details pertaining to indexed views.

That said however, we can definitely address the **performance** side of this. Couple of points:

- How many rows are in the tables `a`, `,b`, `c`? Are they even tables? OR are they themselves views?
- It's advisable for a myriad of reasons, including performance, to not perform `select *`, perhaps you can be more selective.
- Can you post your execution plan?